# Rspec ruby on rails : Haversine gem return nil value when write unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, haversine

I used Rspec to test a methode writen to mesure distance between to points with Haversine gem :

```
# GET /api/v1/angular/sites/:id/distances
  def stores_distances
    site     = Site.find params[ :id ]
    distances = Store.current.map do |store|
      {
        name: store.name,
        value: Haversine.distance(
                site.address.latitude,
                site.address.longitude,
                store.address.latitude,
                store.address.longitude
              ).round(2)
      }
    end

    render json: {
      distances: distances.to_json
    }
  end
```

I want to test 2 cases : if the method return a 200 status, return an array of distances.

here what I did :

```
describe " GET #stores_distances" do
    before :each do
      @site_address   = create :address, latitude: 48.85837009999999, longitude: 2.2944813000000295
      @store_address  = create :address, latitude: 48.8633604, longitude: 2.30189710000002
      @site    = create :site, address: @site_address
      @store   = create :store, address: @store_address

      get :stores_distances, params: { id: @site.id }
    end

    it "should return 200" do
      expect( response.status ).to be_ok
    end

    it "should return an array of distances" do
      expect( response.body ).to have_node(distances)
    end
end
```

I got this error :

> Api::V1::Angular::SitesController  GET #stores_distances should
>   return 200
>        Failure/Error:
>          value: Haversine.distance(
>                  site.address.latitude,
>                  site.address.longitude,
>                  store.address.latitude,
>                  store.address.longitude
>                ).round(2)
>
> ```
>  TypeError:
>    nil can't be coerced into Float
> ```

Comment: could you post full stacktrace?

Comment: What does `Store.current` return? Are you sure all the stores that are returned have lat/long set?

Comment: Thanks, you're right by default the project create on default store that doesn't have lat/long value, I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the stores have `nil` lat or long. Ensure that all stores returned from `Store.current` have initialized coordinates.

Comment: good catch you're right, I fixed that now I got this error on  "it "should return an array of distances" do
      expect( response.body ).to have_node(distances)
    end" 
I got this on my terminal :

     Failure/Error: expect( response.body ).to have_node(@distances)
       expected to have node called: '[]'. Got: '{"distances":"[{\"name\":\"Moulin EURL-533\",\"value\":0.78}]"}'

Comment: `distances` or `@distances` is empty

Comment: this is a good result : Got: '{"distances":"[{\"name\":\"Moulin EURL-533\",\"value\":0.78}]"}' ----------- i want to test it if it's an array of hash ! can you help !